# Delete an array element using event.getSource().get("v.name")

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, array

I try to get index, but it's always -1.

JS:

```
close : function(component, event, helper) {
    let vacancies = component.get("v.vacancies");  //an array
    let vacancy = event.getSource().get("v.name");  //name - the obct's Id from iteration

    const index = vacancies.indexOf(vacancy);        
    vacancies.splice(index, 1);        
    component.set("v.vacancies", vacancies);
},
```

cmp:

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.vacancies}" var="vacancy">
    <span class="spanButtonClose">
        <lightning:buttonIcon name="{!vacancy.Id}" iconName="utility:close" onclick="{!c.close}"/>
    </span>
</aura:iteration>
```

What is wrong here? It's just delete the last one object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Aura:iteration` has an attribute called as `indexVar`, why not use it?

Also from Event docs:

> In the client-side controller, you can use one of the following
>   methods to find out which button was clicked.
>
> event.getSource().getLocalId() returns the aura:id of the clicked
>   button.
>
> event.getSource().get("v.name") returns the name of the clicked
>   button.

Markup:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.vacancies}" var="vacancy" indexVar="index" >
    <span class="spanButtonClose">
        <lightning:buttonIcon name="{!index}" iconName="utility:close" onclick="{!c.close}"/>
    </span>
</aura:iteration>
```

JS Code:

```
close : function(component, event, helper) {
    let vacancies = component.get("v.vacancies");  //an array
    let toDeletIndex =  event.getSource().get("v.name");
    console.log(toDeletIndex );


    vacancies.splice(toDeletIndex, 1);        
    component.set("v.vacancies", vacancies);
},
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm

Comment: Now it deletes only first element) `alert(toDeletIndex);` give me `undefined`

Comment: @YagamiRaito, Am sorry I posted bit incorrect code. I have updated it with references.

Answer (score 0):

if vacancies.indexOf(vacancy) returns -1 means that the javascript didn't found the key on the array

may be check if you should have vacancy.id instead of vacancy.Id

Comment: Same. It's JS case sensitive, not lightning's component.

Comment: It's also alert the right Id, so... The problem is in another place. I just don't know, can we use the name of an element for indexOf or not.